# Dot Net character literals

Tags: .net

I remember a long time ago when I was working with characters in .NET.  The value taken from the SQL database (char field) was stored in a dot net char variable as: "a         " (a series of blank spaces after the character).  This bug in my application caused problems.

Can anyone explain when this happens as I cannot seem to recreate the behaviour and I want to avoid bugs in the application I am working on.

Comment: It never happens. You may be confusing characters and strings.

Comment: Just something to clarify: `CHAR` (and `VARCHAR` for that matter) in SQL is not the same as `Char` in .NET, it's more closely associated with `String`.

Comment: Besides, character literals are a feature of programming languages, not of .NET. Which language are you referring to?

Comment: I see.  Could you explain when it happens with Strings? i.e.  a value is stored in the database as "value" and is loaded into a dot net variable as: "value      ". (note that there are spaces after the word value).

Comment: Bug in the dbase table is more likely.  Like making the column type nchar (fixed length string) instead of nvarchar (variable length string)

Comment: @Hans, I think your answer might be what I am looking for.  If a value is stored in a nvarchar as "a" (no spaces), then I suppose it would be stored in a dot net String variable with blank spaces after the a?

Comment: If you store "A" in a "char(5)" column in the database, you'll fetch the string "A    " in your .Net program.  Simply call Trim()!  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxbw3kwc.aspx

Comment: paulsm4, there is one space in the literal example "A ".  Are there suppose to be 4?

Comment: @w0051977 - that's what I wsa trying to say.  If you define "char(5)" (or an equivalent), then you get five characters in the database ... even if you only think you're inserting one character.  Your "A" and five spaces.  That's just the way it works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CHAR` data type in SQL Server is a *fixed size* field.

So for `CHAR(2)`, if you only populate it with a single character, a space will be added as padding (and more spaces for larger `CHAR` fields).

When read from the DB, you will get these spaces as well. This is not an error.

You should be using the correct data type for your database fields - if you have variable length text, use `VARCHAR` (or `NVARCHAR`), not `CHAR`.

Comment: Does the database automatically remove whitespaces when you query it.  e.g. select * from testchar where charfield='a', returns one row, however the length of charfield is 10.

Comment: @w0051977 - Off the top of my head, no they don't. So such a query will not return any results.

Comment: Thanks.  I have run a test and it appears that whitespaces are removed from the end of the character, so the query did return a result?

Comment: @w0051977 - OK, don't work much with `CHAR`, so my memory was wrong. But the returned result would be 10 characters long.

Comment: Like I said above: use "trim()".  Either in your SQL select, and/or String.Trim() after you read the results in .Net.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bug. CHAR in SQL is a fixed length and pads with spaces to the length of the column definition. By "dot net char variable", I assume you are talking about a string datatype and not an actual array of chars.

If you want variable length strings without padding, then use VARCHAR or NVARCHAR.